# Wordpress Blog Info Transfered into other pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is it possible to draw information from a WordPress blog post and use it on another page?

Such as using a title and date that was submitted on a blog post and display it on the home page?

I know this sounds like a newbie question, but I am not too familiar with WordPress yet.

Comment: please try something first and then post your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to login to your wordpress website and download the data of the blog first. 
Read here for more information! 
https://en.support.wordpress.com/export/